# "She would of been a good woman"

Tags: meaning, grammaticality, contractions, dialect, colloquial-language

> "She **would of been** a good woman," The Misfit said, "if **it had been somebody there** to shoot her every minute of her life."
>
> <sub>**Source:** A Good Man is Hard to Find by Flannery O'Connor</sub>

This is an quote from the story "A good man is hard to find" by Flannery O'Connor. Is here "she would of been" a non-standard equivalent of "she would have been"? – And what about the construction "if it had been somebody there…" Is it grammatically OK or is it the expression of O'Connor's play with language?

Comment: You are certainly correct about the first half: "would of" is a spoken corruption of "would **have**." However, I haven't read the story, so it's hard to know what the the second part of the quote means. I assume it's a Southern American dialect expression (based on O'Connor's preferred setting for stories) meaning "if somebody had been there to..." but I'm really not sure.

Comment: Here's how the first mistake comes to be: "Would have" --> "Would've" --> "Would of"  A good explanation of this particular quotation can be found at [Spark Notes](http://www.sparknotes.com/short-stories/a-good-man-is-hard-to-find/quotes.html).  It's the second quotation on the page.

Comment: She was a great short-story writer whose stories are set in the US South; "if it had been somebody there" is a rural southernism for "if somebody had been there".

Comment: Many highly regarded authors, and not just those using Southern American English (*eg* John Dos Passos), use "would of" and "could of" to represent the colloquial speech of their characters. Nowadays, many people write *would of* instead of *would've* because their language skills do not seem to include the standard contracted form (*would've*).

Comment: @δοῦλος: More to the point, a surprisingly large number of people explicitly articulate *"I would **OV** said this properly, but I don't understand basic English grammar"*.

Answer (score 3):

This is O'Connor playing with language, representing either the Misfit's incorrect use of grammar or the way his speech sounds. The correct locutions are "would have been" and "if there had been."