# "Of" being used instead of "have"

Tags: prepositions, grammar-myths

Recently I've seen many people on Twitter use "of" instead of "have".
Eg. Ben Stokes tweeted after the world cup final, " So proud to of represented my country in a world cup final"

I don't want to generalise, but I think I've seen this used by primarily British people. Is it slang or are my basics weak?

Comment: Never consider *social media* English as standard English, especially Twitter!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is it all about this usage? would of+verb](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/53105/what-is-it-all-about-this-usage-would-ofverb). Also [“She would of been a good woman”](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/51418/) and [Meaning of “you'd of thought”](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/41407/), among others.

Comment: Misused equally in the United States, but it is usually caught and corrected in primary school if students are paying attention. We're an illiterate lot at times.

Answer (score 3):

It is wrong to use "of" there.  It is used because it's hard to *say* "have" there without spluttering over our words.  Therefore, we tend to pronounce it just like "of" and then start writing it as "of".

---

Further reading:

[Would have vs. Would of | e Learn English language](http://www.elearnenglishlanguage.com/blog/english-mistakes/would-have-vs-would-of/)
[Have and of - Commonly Confused Words](http://grammar.about.com/od/words/a/haveofgloss.htm)

Comment: +1 Good answer. The misuse preceded and reaches far beyond the internet.

Answer (score 2):

The contraction of "could have" is "could've" and sounds very much like "could of". I suppose over time "have" got replaced by "of" since it seems to require less physical effort to pronounce.

Comment: It's not so much that it was replaced, and more so that people hear it and learn from hearing instead of reading and learning that `could've` means `could have` and not `could of`.

Answer (score 1):

> I don't want to generalise, but I think I've seen this used by
>   primarily British people. Is it slang or are my basics weak?

It is simply internet slang, and a scramble for words to fit into the 140 limit. People started shortening `have` to `'ave`, then finally to `of`, so that [they can get rid of those extra two letters](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/words/could-of-or-could-have).

Comment: Doesn't `'ave` have the same number of characters as `have`?

Comment: I believe he means in common speech